# Allow FTP only through VPN

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vpn

I've gone through all the possible threads and answers and still I'm not sure how to achieve this. Is following scenario even possible in the first place?

I've ubuntu 16.04 server which has OpenVPN installed and running. I can connect to this VPN through Windows client. The server also hosts some files that I need an access to, and I would like to use FTP for time being (SFTP is better, I know). Can I make it so, that the FTP port is only accessible through my VPN connection?

Because I'm not sure and this same question has been asked hundreths of times, could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options.

1. Configure your FTP server to listen only your OpenVPN interface/address.
2. Use iptables to filter out traffic from other than OpenVPN interface. If your default policy is DROP and your OpenVPN interface name is `tun0` to accept all traffic from OpenVPN interface:

   ```
   iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
   ```

   or alternatively accept matching by your OpenVPN network, for example in case your OpenVPN configuration uses addresses in 10.8.0.0/24 network:

   ```
   iptables -A INPUT -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
   ```

   If you want more specific rules to limit the rules for only FTP, you need to match FTP ports and for passive FTP also use `RELATED` target. Quite good explanation is provided by [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/38425) on server fault. Configuring matching rule by port number is simpler for SSH (and SFTP) since it doesn't use any other incoming ports.

   When your default policy for OUTPUT chain is DROP you need to also have similar rules to allow outgoing traffic (`-A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT` and `-A OUTPUT -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT` respectively)

Comment: Thank you for this! Great response and exactly what I asked. Because I'm really new with Linux and the iptables seems just so daunting, is it possible to do the same with ufw?

Something like: sudo ufw allow out on tun0 to any port 21

Comment: I am not familiar with uwf, however something like that should work (your example missing  `proto tcp`) if I read the [`man`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/ufw.8.html) page correctly.